# Neo4j - How to get current version via REST

Tags: rest, neo4j

How can i get the current running neo4j-server version (or in general server informations) via REST? Is there any "/status" URI or something similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [REST API documentation page](https://neo4j.com/docs/rest-docs/current/), quote:

> The API described in this manual been deprecated and will be removed in Neo4j 4.0. Cypher and procedures should be used instead, either via the HTTP API, or via Bolt using the official drivers.

neither of http://localhost:7474/db/manage/server/version and http://localhost:7474/db/data/ endpoints works anymore since version 4+. Assuming the authentication to db is `--env NEO4J_AUTH=username/password` (just example of `docker run` option), the recommended way is to use HTTP API as follows:

```
POST http://localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/commit
Accept: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Basic dXNlcm5hbWU6cGFzc3dvcmQ=

{
  "statements": [
    {
      "statement": "CALL dbms.components()"
    }
  ]
}
```

and the response is:

```
http://localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/commit

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 27 Jan 2022 09:20:13 GMT
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 147

{
  "results": [
    {
      "columns": [
        "name",
        "versions",
        "edition"
      ],
      "data": [
        {
          "row": [
            "Neo4j Kernel",
            [
              "4.2.3"
            ],
            "community"
          ],
          "meta": [
            null,
            null,
            null
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "errors": []
}
```

Answer (score 20):

Try this one,
Get http://localhost:7474/db/manage/server/version
This will give you a json response like
{
  "edition" : "community",
  "version" : "2.3.3"
}

Comment: this is the right answer. @Alebon should change it.

Comment: @DmitryParanyushkin i second that. the accepted answer is not really an API call. it returns a basic HTML page with links for further exploration.

Comment: for version 4 upwards see https://stackoverflow.com/a/70876203 ↓

Answer (score 7):

Making a GET request against the server data root will return this info:

```
GET http://localhost:7474/db/data/
```

The call will return a JSON object.  Server version is in the key "neo4j_version". This is [documented here](https://neo4j.com/docs/rest-docs/current/#rest-api-service-root).

Comment: THANKS Josh! Oh my goodness, have missed that one... It was too simple ;)

Comment: This url does not return version for 3.x

Comment: Yes, this answer is no longer correct. I would change it if I could.